# Why chef nodes retain roles after removing them?

Tags: chef

We have a few servers, with a usual mix of roles and recipes.

We've found a problem though: after a role has been removed from a server (specifically: removed from its run list, and re-provisioned), subsequent searches for that role, both via knife search, and from recipes, still return  the server.

Why is that? When inspecting the node (knife node show), the role is not present in the "Roles" list, so the results don't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, we've discovered a very misleading functionality of Chef, that is, all the attributes are searched, at any level of depth, without regard for the name being a "special" one.

This means that if a machine has `roles = ['smartpants']`, and an attribute `node[:foo][:bar][:roles] = 'fancypants'`, the search result for `roles:fancypants` will include such machine.

In some cases, it's reasonable to have such structure, which without knowing this details, will lead to lots of hairpulling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the role is not appearing in the node's JSON anymore after it's been reprovisioned? It's possible that when you're reprovisioning, you're overriding the run list the server has stored -- possibly with `/etc/chef/firstboot.json` -- and that this run list is being persisted back to the server, even though you removed it previously.

Comment: took more than an year to figure this out. answer below :)